# Dojo custom build to several files

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

How I can build the dojotoolkit sources to several files? I want build all to dojo-all.js, dijit-all.js, dojox-all.js and a folder with css and images.

I found solutions only if you specify dependencies, but I don't known what modules I will use, and I want to include all.

Comment: Setup a layer for each file you want in your profile.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a single file build, then you may create a layer on top of `dojo/dojo` and include an initializer layout to your app. All remaining dependencies will be included automatically.

You layer config should be more or less like this:

```
layers: {
    'dojo/dojo' : {
        customBase: true,
        boot: true,
        include: ['my-app/init'] // a module that boots your app.
    }
},
```

Checkout [this small project](https://github.com/eduardo-matos/single-file-dojo-build) that I created for a tutorial showing how to create a single file build (sorry, the README is in Portuguese =/).